# SQL Server - Hibernate select SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to use Hibernate with SQL Server .

I want to select the rows from SQL Server and cast them to Places objects.

I will write the codes I tried and exceptions I got.

```
List places = session.createQuery("FROM PLACES").list();
for (Iterator iterator = places.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
   Place place = (Place) iterator.next(); 
}
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

This code generates

```
select  from
```

and since SQL Server needs something between select and from this query fails

So I tried to change the code to

```
List places = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID,NAME FROM [PLACES].[dbo].[PLACES]").list();
   for (Iterator iterator = places.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
      Place place = (Place) iterator.next(); 
   }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Since this query returns an Object[] I can not cast it.

How can I get rows and cast them to Places objects

Mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.places.general.Place" table="PLACES" schema="dbo">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column length="100" name="NAME" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HQL statement you have to use the Java class name, not the table name:

```
List places = session.createQuery("FROM Place").list();
```

or

```
List places = session.createQuery("FROM com.places.general.Place").list();
```

And your second try returns a list of arrays of Object, each array first element is id, second is name, which have to be casted to Integer and String separately.